# Verifiable encryption: Comparison between FS01 and CS03

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, discrete-logarithm, verifiable-encryption

Consider the following two verifiable encryption schemes for Discrete Logarithm.

FS01: [“One Round Threshold Discrete-Log Key Generation without Private Channels” by Pierre-Alain Fouque and Jacques Stern](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-44586-2_22),
Section 3.2, "A Proof of Fairness".

CS03: [“Practical Verifiable Encryption and Decryption of Discrete Logarithms” by Jan Camenisch and Victor Shoup.](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2003/27290126/27290126.pdf)

They both rely on Paillier Encryption and originate from around the same time.

**Question:** Does somebody have a deeper understanding of similarity and differences? Is one to be preferred over the other?